# How to restore selected files from a Windows 7 backup on a Windows 8.1 machine

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, windows-backup

Moving from a Windows 7 computer to a Windows 8.1 computer, I'm stumped at how to read the Win7 backup off the USB drive so I can pick specific files to restore on the new Windows 8.1 machine.

I did the backup on the Windows 7 machine using the Windows Backup and Restore feature.

Comment: The backed up data should be stored in a VHD file, which you could mount using the Disk Management applet, as explained here: [Quick Tip: Restore individual files from a System Image in Windows 8](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-restore-individual-files-from-a-system-image-in-windows-8/), [How to Restore Files and Folders From Windows 7 System Image Backup](http://www.sysprobs.com/restore-files-folders-windows-7-system-image-backup)

Comment: http://winsupersite.com/windows-8/windows-8-tip-use-windows-7-system-image-backup